# How to load and use tinyMCE in magento2?

Tags: magento2, requirejs

i have element

```
<h2 id="editable" class="editable">Editable header</h2>
```

i tried to use

```
<script>
   require([
    'jquery',
    'tinymce'

    ],function($){
        tinyMCE.init({
              elements: 'div.editable',
              inline: true,
              toolbar: 'undo redo',
              menubar: false
        });
})
</script>
```

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: yep. I follow this code you share. It work, but not show toolbar!

Comment: Have you remove var and clear cache

Comment: i has flush and clean cache.

Comment: Please check more details in core module of magento, how to use this toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

> You are forgot to pass **tinyMCE** parameter in function.

**Try below code :**

```
<script>
   require([
    'jquery',
    'tinymce'

    ],function($,tinyMCE){
        tinyMCE.init({
              elements: 'div.editable',
              inline: true,
              toolbar: 'undo redo',
              menubar: false
        });
})
</script>
```

Also please clear the cache and after clearing the cache use below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have missing tinyMCE in function parameter.**

```
<script>
   require([
    'jquery',
    'tinymce'

    ],function($,tinyMCE){
        tinyMCE.init({
              elements: 'div.editable',
              inline: true,
              toolbar: 'undo redo',
              menubar: false
        });
})
</script>
```

Remove var folder and clear cache and try 
again.